# Payment solutions for digital product (license code)?

Tags: web-development, api, web-services, online-payment, login

I have ads on my website, as well as a "consider buying our mobile app" nag screen that appears from time to time. Nothing too annoying, but still a bit of a nuisance for heavy users of the site.

I just put up a "Support us" -button via PayPal, but then I realized that it might make more sense to have the option to pay either a one-time fee or a subscription to remove the ads and the nag screen.

I considered redirecting users to a page that gives them a "license code" after a successful payment. They would then enter the code on the website to activate the ad removal,and a cookie would be used to remember it. I might also need to use Instant Payment Notifications to handle subscriptions though. And users would have to re-enter the activation code if they change browsers, as it would only be persisted on the client as a cookie. And I think I read something about the redirect page not working the same if they pay with a credit card or by other means?

The PayPal solution seems a bit convoluted - are there any easy to use solutions for this type of scenario, where all you really want to "sell" is an activation code?

Comment: Don't think you need a license code type activation for a website - simply have a user able to log in (to post comments, etc anyway right?) and if they pay the $x per month or one time, then you mark that in your db and don't serve ads to them (simple if-then check before calling advert code).  Check out what fark.com does with bare fark and totalfark

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the hassle of creating a full fledged user management system, as there really isn't any use for it on this site. That's why I'm looking for a simple solution that would require minimum coding on my part...

Comment: if you don't craete an user system you won't be able to disable the adds to the user. if your system don't know who's the user, they won't know who is the one that required the adds to be disabled

Answer (score 0):

you have to capture the authorization and payment, after you got the confirmation you'll be able to execute the required functions to disable the adds for that user.

but for that you'll require server side code to handle the payment

here's a logic example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699907/paypal-payment-and-net-confirmation-check-page